# How to reduce boilerplate with monocle in scala

Tags: scala, lenses, monocle-scala

I've refactored my code for [day 12](http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/12) of advent of code by using monocle, a lens library in scala.

Is it possible to improve this code :

```
  type Register = String
  type Mem = Map[String, Int]

  @Lenses
  case class State(mem: Mem, pointer: Int)

  def processInstruction(instructions: Seq[Instruction]): State => State = { s =>
    (instructions(s.pointer) match {
      case Inc(r) =>
        State.pointer.modify( _ + 1) andThen (State.mem composeLens at(r)).modify(_.map(_ + 1))
      case Dec(r) =>
        State.pointer.modify( _ + 1) andThen (State.mem composeLens at(r)).modify(_.map(_ - 1))
      case CpyInt(v, to) =>
        State.pointer.modify( _ + 1) andThen (State.mem composeLens at(to)).set(Some(v))
      case CpyReg(from, to) =>
        State.pointer.modify( _ + 1) andThen (State.mem composeLens at(to)).set(Some(s.mem(from)))
      case Jnz(r, v) => if (r != "1" && s.mem(r) == 0)
        State.pointer.modify( _ + 1)
      else
        State.pointer.modify( _ + v )
    }).apply(s)
  }
```

And here is another try, separating the modification of each field

```
  def processInstruction2(instructions: Seq[Instruction]): State => State = { s =>
    val ptr = instructions(s.pointer) match {
      case Jnz(r, v) if !(r != "1" && s.mem(r) == 0) => State.pointer.modify(_ + v)
      case _ => State.pointer.modify(_ + 1)
    }

    val mem = instructions(s.pointer) match {
    case Inc(r) => (State.mem composeLens at(r)).modify(_.map(_ + 1))
    case Dec(r) => (State.mem composeLens at(r)).modify(_.map(_ - 1))
    case CpyInt(v, to) => (State.mem composeLens at(to)).set(Some(v))
    case CpyReg(from, to) => (State.mem composeLens at(to)).set(Some(s.mem(from)))
    case _ => identity[State]
  }
    (ptr andThen mem)(s)
  }
```

One more question : is there a way to use `Map.withDefaultValue` with monocle ?

The full code is here : https://gist.github.com/YannMoisan/b8ba25afc041d88706545527d9ec1988

Comment: I would use `index` instead of `at` when you want to modify the value inside of the map, e.g. `(State.mem composeOptional index(r)).modify(_ + 1)` instead of `(State.mem composeLens at(r)).modify(_.map(_ + 1))`

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use the second approach, because it separates handling of two fields.
However, the functions shouldn't be interpreted in sequence (`andThen`), but rather they should be combined as `PartialFunction`s with `orElse`.

```
def processInstruction3(instructions: Seq[Instruction]): State => State = {
  val ptr: PartialFunction[Instruction, State => State] = {
    case Jnz(r, v) =>
      State.pointer.modify(_ + v)
  }

  val incPointer: State => State = State.pointer.modify( _ + 1)
  def reg(r: String): Lens[State, Option[Int]] = State.mem composeLens at(r)
  val mem: PartialFunction[Instruction, State => State] = {
    case Inc(r) => reg(r).modify(_.orElse(Option(0)).map(_ + 1))
    case Dec(r) => reg(r).modify(_.orElse(Option(0)).map(_ - 1))
    case CpyInt(v, to) => reg(to).set(Some(v))
    case CpyReg(from, to) => s => reg(to).set(reg(from).get(s))(s)
  }
  val interpreter = ptr orElse (mem andThen (_ andThen incPointer))
  s => instructions.foldLeft(s)((s, i) => interpreter(i)(s))
}
```

**UPDATE** (after the Yann Moisan comment)

The execution may not terminate in case of infinite loop in user's program. So instead of the `foldLeft` we need some recursive function that will extract the next instruction by pointer:

```
@tailrec
def loop(s: State): State = {
  if(s.pointer>=instructions.length)
    s
  else {
    val instruction = instructions(s.pointer)
    val nextState = interpreter(instruction)(s)
    loop(nextState)
  }
}
loop _
```

(The last line of `processInstruction3` should be replaced with the above code)

Comment: instructions should not be executed in order because of the jump (jnz) instruction.

Comment: Here are two aspects. One is modularity - handling of instructions of various kinds separately. And this is achieved by `PartialFunction`. The other aspect is the sequential run of two steps for normal instructions (execution and pointer advance). Both aspects are handled properly in `processInstruction3`. In the `processInstruction2` `(ptr andThen mem)` in case of `Jnz` it will be also handled by the second pattern matching block (luckily there is no other similar instruction and it'll go through default case).